# $get gets a object expected error, but getElementByID not - why?

Tags: jquery

I use a lot of JS in my ASP.Net page. At the moment I try to access a lot of labels in usercontrols. In normal labels without UCs, $get and getElementByID both work. But now not.

```
        alert(document.getElementById('<%= ucBW1.FindControl("lblTime").ClientID %>').innerHTML);
      alert($get('<%= ucBW1.FindControl("lblTime").ClientID %>').innerHTML);
```

So, the usercontrol-control-id (what a word) is found correctly by both, but the $get gets an "object expected". (Of curse I tried it seperatly).

Any ideas?

(The alert is only to test what I get, I want to change the innerHTML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
alert($('#<%= ucBW1.FindControl("lblTime").ClientID %>').html());
```

In JQuery, '#' means that you're trying to get element by it's id.

Jimmeh is right, I misread that part. The [get method](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/get) is used to return actual DOM elements that matched, here is a usage of get function in your case :

```
alert($('#<%= ucBW1.FindControl("lblTime").ClientID %>').get(0).innerHTML);
```

Also, you can use html function to set item's innerHTML like that :

```
$('#<%= ucBW1.FindControl("lblTime").ClientID %>').html('<b>some stuff here</b>');
```

Comment: Thank you, works. 1) Why? 2) What was my problem? 3) Sadly your HTML() I can't assign a text, which I must, see edit please.

Comment: $get and $.get are a little different.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jquery, use

```
alert($('#<%= ucBW1.FindControl("lblTime").ClientID %>').html());
```

Comment: Thank you, works. 1) Why? 2) What was my problem? 3) Sadly your HTML() I can't assign a text, which I must, see edit please.

Comment: You can assign text to html() by doing html('text here'). It will replace whatever is there. 

jquery requires the # for element Id's, which is why it didn't work i think.

Answer (score 0):

If it expects an **object**, you can't feed it with a **string** (the ID is a string). Doesn't `ucBW1.FindControl("lblTime")` return the object? If so, you don't need to append `.ClientID` to get its ID.

Comment: jquery and asp.net controls aren't the most compatible things in the world. Although i've not tried what you've suggested, I would bet money on it not working.